# How to insert new guid on sql select statement for a column

Tags: sql, c#-4.0

I have following select statement:

```
string query = @"Select Sudent, " + Guid.NewGuid() + " as  Id, Name, DOB from Student where Name = Ken";
```

then i am using this statement in bulkcopy command to do an insert in table. But problem is it is generating only 1 guid for all 5 rows and throws an error. How can i get different guid for all 5 (or any number of rows select gets) rows for column Id.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

```
string query = @"Select Student, newid() as  Id, Name, DOB from Student where Name = Ken";
```

Comment: And if the OP is using Oracle? Or MySQL? Or PostGres? Or some other DB?

Answer (score 5):

For SQL Server:

```
SELECT Student, NEWID() AS Id, Name, DOB
    FROM Student
    WHERE Name = 'Ken'
```

For MySQL:

```
SELECT Student, UUID() AS Id, Name, DOB
    FROM Student
    WHERE Name = 'Ken'
```

For Oracle:

```
SELECT Student, SYS_GUID() AS Id, Name, DOB
    FROM Student
    WHERE Name = 'Ken'
```

Answer (score 2):

Since you are using C#, I will assume SQL Server.

SQL Server has a built in function - [`NEWID`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms190348.aspx) - it will create a GUID.

```
string query = @"Select Sudent, NEWID() as  Id, Name, DOB 
                 from Student where Name = Ken";
```